# Add scroll bar to appending box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a box on my webpage that you can drag an image onto and it will show it's details of the image that are stored in my database. The box appends when images are loaded into it but I'm wondering how I could add a scroll bar to my box instead of it appending all the way down the screen. Here is my JS code:

```
    $("#drop").append("<span><img id='t"+id+"' src='images/"+pick[id].src+"' title='"+    
           pick[id].desc+"' alt='"+
           pick[id].alt+"' class='thumb'  />&nbsp;"+pick[id].desc+", Price £"+
           pick[id].price+"</span><br />");
```

and my CSS:

```
   #drop{   
   float:right;
   margin-left:2%;
   width:30%;
   background-color:9CF;    
   }
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're asking but maybe this could help.  Give the `#drop` element a fixed height and add the `overflow` property to its style.

```
#drop{   
   float:right;
   margin-left:2%;
   width:30%;
   height: 300px; // Or whatever satisfies you.
   overflow-y: auto;
   background-color:9CF;    
}
```

Comment: Okay, this is exactly what I was asking for so thanks! however, a feature of my webpage was that you could drag the image back out of the box to delete it's details from showing. This doesn't allow the images to leave the box, although it does still delete them when dragged to the delete box

Comment: Check out this example: http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxDataView/samples/05_drag-n-drop/07_auto_scroll.html. It's not using images but it'll give you an idea.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm looking for, but I can't seem to figure out from the source code what to add to mine